# NDK How to get a list of all process running?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there anyway to get all the process currently running on the device using pure C/C++ code using the NDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android is Linux for most of this kind of thing, and the official way to do this on Linux is to read the `/proc` file system. That's what the `ps` command line program does. Here's a snippet from [Android's ps program](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/system/core.git;a=blob;f=toolbox/ps.c;h=bc50cfa971e9f4021b2468789dea4c6b3fb72681;hb=HEAD#l222), which lives in the platform/system/core repository:

```
d = opendir("/proc");

while((de = readdir(d)) != 0){
    if(isdigit(de->d_name[0])){
        int pid = atoi(de->d_name);
        if(!pidfilter || (pidfilter == pid)) {
            ps_line(pid, 0, namefilter);
            if(threads) ps_threads(pid, namefilter);
        }
    }
}
```

The `ps_line` function is pretty large, but the part that you want is where it reads `/proc/<pid>/stat`. From that file you can get the process name easily enough as the format is `PID (process-name) other stuff` - just look for the first paren and parse until the closing one.